# In kafka, When producing message with transactional, Consumer offset doubled up

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm making project using springboot 2, kafk 2.2.0, spring-kafka 2.2.5

I maked `kafka exactly once` environment and message producing and consuming was well.

BUT `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` saied like this.

```
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG
test_topic      0          23              24              1   
test_topic      1          25              26              1   
test_topic      2          21              22              1
```

I just send only one message to kafka, but `LOG-END-OFFSET` doubled up and 1 lag remain always. (In my java app, producing and consuming works as intended)

I don't know why LOG-END-OFFSET doubled up.

If removing `exactly once` config, there is no problem in `LOG-END-OFFSET` and `CURRENT-OFFSET` count.

It is my `kafkaTemplate` setup codes.

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> producerProperties = new HashMap<>();
        producerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092";
        producerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        producerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        // exactly once producer setup
        producerProperties.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");

        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerProperties, new StringSerializer(), new JsonSerializer<>(KafkaStaticOptions.OBJECT_MAPPER));
        factory.setTransactionIdPrefix("my.transaction.");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public KafkaTransactionManager<String, Object> kafkaTransactionManager(
        ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }
```

My producer code.

```
kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(kt -> kt.send("test_topic", "test data hahaha"));
```

I checked when LOG-END-OFFSET doubled up, and it is `produce transaction commit` timing.

What did I do wrong configuration?

Comment: this makes little sense. If log-end offset doubles and lag remains 1, that means current offset also was increased/doubled+1. Are you sure you are sending just 1 message?

Comment: yes. Surely I sended just 1 message, and my consumer consumed jus 1 message.

Comment: and the current offset also was increased > +1?

Comment: CURRENT-OFFSET doubled up too, except consuming first message. When consuming first message, CURRENT-OFFSET  added 1 and 1 lag appeared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using transactions, Kafka insert "[control batches](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#controlbatch)" in the logs to indicate if messages were part of a transaction.

These batches are also assigned offsets so this is why you see the offsets increasing by 2 even though you only sent a single record.

If you want to check for yourself, you can use the DumpLogSegments tool to display the content of your logs and see the control batch:

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files /tmp/kafka-logs/mytopic-0/00000000000000000000.log
Dumping /tmp/kafka-logs/mytopic-0/00000000000000000000.log
Starting offset: 0
baseOffset: 0 lastOffset: 0 count: 1 baseSequence: 0 lastSequence: 0 producerId: 0 producerEpoch: 0 partitionLeaderEpoch: 0 isTransactional: true isControl: false position: 0 CreateTime: 1558083247264 size: 10315 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE crc: 3531536908 isvalid: true
baseOffset: 1 lastOffset: 1 count: 1 baseSequence: -1 lastSequence: -1 producerId: 0 producerEpoch: 0 partitionLeaderEpoch: 0 isTransactional: true isControl: true position: 10315 CreateTime: 1558083247414 size: 78 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE crc: 576574952 isvalid: true
```

I used the transactional producer to send a single record and you can see that the 2nd entry has `isControl: true`.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it's likely. As mentioned when using transactions, offsets mean something a bit different

Comment: Are you saying offset hopping is ok and expected when using transactions?

Comment: Yes, transaction boundaries use an offset. Messages from aborted transactions also keep their offsets