# Can there be gaps in Kafka's partition ids?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm looking for a specification of Kafka's partition ids. If a topic has `n` partitions, are its partition ids guaranteed to be `0 1 2 ... n-1` or are there ever scenarios in which gaps can appear, e. g. the partition ids are `0 2 3`?

It's not possible to delete a specific Kafka partition, so at least a gap can't be produced this way.

Comment: In case is you are using Kafka transactions you can have gaps in offset(messages which you can;t see). you can have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183132/14394219)

Comment: @artiomi yes offsets, but this is about partition ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. When you create a topic, you specify the number of partitions and they are created from 0 to N-1. Then you cannot delete partitions so you cannot create holes (or even deleting the last one). You can increase them, but Kafka will add from N to M-1. And so on.